# How to stop recursive function php [laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, recursive-query

I use Laravel,
I have table tbl_menu

```php
//In model: 
public function child()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Menu', 'parentID', 'ID');
    }
```

```php
//in controller
public function getCountChild()
    {
        $menu= Menu::where('ID', 2318)->first();
        echo '<br>Input: ' . $menu->id;
        $gioihan=20;
        $countChild  = $this->recursiveCountChild($menu, $gioihan);
        echo '<br>countChild  : ' . $countChild  ;
    }
```

```php
public function recursiveCountChild($parent, $gioihan, $limit = 0)
    {
        $childs = $parent->child;
        $limit += $childs->count();

        if ($limit < $gioihan && $childs->count() > 0) {
            foreach ($childs as $item) {
                echo '<br>'. $item->affID.', ';
                //$this->dequyCountChild($item, $gioihan, $limit);
                return $this->dequyCountChild($item, $gioihan, $limit);
            }
        }elseif($limit>=$gioihan){
            echo "<br>Done: ".$limit;
            return $limit;
        }
        return $limit;
    }
```

**And Result:**
[bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBovv.jpg)

I want to get $limit but can not.

it seems, they only run on the left and don't check on the right.
help me. Thanks

Comment: You should just put a parentid on all the posts and then get them by that rather than firing of 20+ queries

Comment: I see what you mean, but that's not my point.

Comment: Is this your mean? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404794/recursive-function-not-returning-all-children